# Does Hinduism encourage dead body preservation?

Tags: vedas, puranas, death, body

I have had a doubt that do hindus encourage  body preservation as Muslims and Egyptian did?

Comment: No, for the most part we believe in cremation, not burial.  Christians and Muslims bury their dead because they believe that at the end of the world there will be bodily resurrection of the dead, which we don't believe.  In any case, there are some cases where a Sanyasi goes into Samadhi and their body is preserved, but most people are cremated.

Comment: Hindus cremate.From where you got this doubt in the first place? I presume there has to be some source.Please tell us about that.

Comment: Hindus believe they are a soul with a body; Westerners believe they are a body with a soul. Sometimes saints/sadhus that are considered great parmahamsas will have their bodies preserved in crypts. Anandamayi Ma's body is in a mandir in Kankhal. If a sadhu dies near the Ganga, especially around Kankhal, Haridwar, or Varanasi, the body is simply put into the river without cremation as his 'cremation' already took place when his sannyas vows were taken. Other than that, cremation occurs. Some jivas are so attached to the body that they do not give it up until they see it gone.